# Lead and lag in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of [Oracle's LEAD and LAG](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/LagLeadAnalyticFunctions.php) in Hbase or some other sort of pattern that will solve my problem. I could write a MapReduce program that does this quite easily, but I'd love to be able to exploit the fact that the data is already sorted in the way I need it to be.

My problem is as follows: I have a rowkey and a value that looks like:

```
(employee name + timestamp) => data:salary
```

So, some example data might be:

```
miller, bob;2010-01-14 => data:salary=90000
miller, bob;2010-11-04 => data:salary=102000
miller, bob;2011-12-03 => data:salary=107000
monty, fred;2010-04-10 => data:salary=19000
monty, fred;2011-09-09 => data:salary=24000
```

What I want to do is calculate the changes of salary, record by record. I want to transform the above data into differences between records:

```
miller, bob;2010-01-14 => data:salarydiff=90000
miller, bob;2010-11-04 => data:salarydiff=12000
miller, bob;2011-12-03 => data:salarydiff=5000
monty, fred;2010-04-10 => data:salarydiff=19000
monty, fred;2011-09-09 => data:salarydiff=5000
```

I'm up for changing the rowkey strategy if necessary.

Comment: if you want a record by record diff - why don't you want to write a map/reduce (actually just a map) to do that?

Comment: The problem with a map-only job, is how would you handle the case where two rowkeys for the same individual are spread across two map tasks?

Comment: I have a mapreduce job that does this now; just it seems silly to shuffle the data to the reducers when it's already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is change the key so that the timestamp will be descending (newer salary first)

```
miller, bob;2011-12-03 => data:salary=107000
miller, bob;2010-11-04 => data:salary=102000
miller, bob;2010-01-14 => data:salary=90000
```

Now you can do a simple map job that will scan the table. Then in the map you create a new  Scan to the current key. Scan.next to get the previous salary, calculate the diff and store it in a new column on the current row key
Basically in your mapper class (the one that inherits TableMapper) you override the setup method and get the configuration

```
@Override
protected void setup(Mapper.Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
    table = new HTable(config,<Table Name>);
}
```

Then inside the map you extract the row key from the row parmeter, create the new Scan and continue as explained above

In most cases the next record would be in the same region - occasionally it might go to another regionserver

Comment: Fantastic. I don't know much about querying hbase from Java mapreduce, so I didn't realize `Scan.next` could do this for me.

Comment: Will the scan object be smart enough to not have to do a real query against Hbase?

Comment: probably not - though I haven't tested it